# How to upload data's with uid to firebase android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a reward android studio project with firebase backend. I have create a payment info activity for generate payment in this project. I have create some edit text in this activity ie Name, withdrawal amount, Paytm number contact number etc...

I want to get user id in this section for identify the specific user. How can I get and save user id with this section to firebase with the withdrawal button click. Please help me.

This is my basic code

```
withdrawal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        HashMap<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("amount",enterbalance.getText().toString());
        map.put("paytm",paytm.getText().toString());
        map.put("name",name.getText().toString());
        map.put("email",emailcard.getText().toString());
        map.put("number",altrnbr.getText().toString());

        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("PAYTMWITHDRAWAL").push()
                .setValue(map)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        Log.i("jfbvkj", "onComplete: ");
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.i("jfbvkj", "onFailure: "+e.toString());
                    }
                }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                Log.i("jfbvkj", "onSuccess: ");
            }
        });
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. If you step through the code you shared in a debugger, which is the first line that doesn't do what you want it to do?

Comment: Is any of the listeners you have added triggered?

Answer (score 0):

```
if(FirebaseAuth().getInstance().getCurrentUser()!=null{
     String uid=FirebaseAuth().getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();    
}else{
   //You are not logged in
}
```

above code will help you get user uid at any place but make sure the user is already signed in when calling this code.